# Setting Value to the List property of a class object variable in c#

Tags: c#, reflection

i have a class,

```
public class Test
{
    public int b { get; set; }
    public int c { get; set; }
    public List<Doc> doc=new List<Doc>();
}

Public Class Doc
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
}
```

Here, i can set the value to the Test Variables like,

```
Test test = new Test();
string var1= "b";
PropertyInfo pi= test.GetType().GetProperty(var1);
pi.SetValue(test, Convert.ChangeType(1,pi.PropertyType), null);
```

so i can get test.b as 1. Likewise i need to set the value for doc.
How do i achieve this. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doc` isn't a property; it's a field.

```
        var test = new Test();

        var field = test.GetType().GetField("doc");

        field.SetValue(test, new List<Doc>() { new Doc() });

        Console.WriteLine(test.doc.Count); // 1
```